# On critical points of a large function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system

I am badly stuck at the following:$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{yx^2}{2}-\frac{\alpha x^2}{2}+\alpha yx+\frac{2y^3}{3}+y^2$$. The question is to find the value of $\alpha$ such that $f(x,y)$ has three distinct critical points simultaneously. One is given as $\alpha=0$, but how can we find the other, positive value of $\alpha$. Equating the first partial derivatives to zero leads to non-linear equations, which is tough to solve. How do we proceed?  Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

If you compute the partial derivatives you get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=(x-y)(x-\alpha)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\frac12x^2+\alpha x+2y^2+2y$. So if you want critical points, from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ you have that either $x=y$ or $x=\alpha$. Plug these two values separately in the second equation.

**Edit** 
For
$x=\alpha$ you get
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\alpha,y)=\frac12\alpha^2+2y^2+2y=0$ for  $y=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}%
\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, if $|\alpha|<1$ the points $(\alpha,\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}-\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\alpha,-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}-\frac{1}{2})$ are two critical points. 
When $x=y$ you get  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,x)=-\frac12x^2+\alpha x+2x^2+2x=x(\frac32x+\alpha+2)=0$ for $x=0$ and $x=-\frac23(\alpha+2)$ so you get $(0,0)$ and $(-\frac23(\alpha+2),-\frac23(\alpha+2))$.

Comment: thanks, I miscomputed the first partial derivatives. By the way, is there any good method to solve non-linear equations in general?

Comment: no unfortunately there isn't. Each one is different. If you can factorize it (like I did the first equation), then you are lucky.

Comment: But still, on substitution, i seem to get only one or two critical points. How do I find three distinct points?

Comment: when you plug in $x=\alpha$ you get a quadratic equation in $y$ which for some values of $\alpha$ will give you two distinct $y$. These are two critical point. The third one is when you plug in $x=y$.

Comment: but, at $\alpha=0$, the function has three distinct critical points simulataneously. Similarly, there exists(as pointed out by my professor) another $\alpha$, where there exist three distinct critical points simultaneously. How to find that $\alpha$ is my question. This is somehow elementarily related to bifurcation of degenerate critical points, I believe

Comment: if $x=y$, we can have only one distinct critical point apart from $(0,0)$, which is included in the case $\alpha=0$, isnt it?

Comment: I added more details. You just had to solve the quadratic equations.